# Animate tray icon while processing

Tags: c#, notifyicon, animated

How can I animate the tray icon while the main application is processing? I already tried the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559853/tray-icon-animation), but the icon does not animate during process. I also tried putting the animation in a separate thread but still no luck.

Comment: animation worked with System.Timers.Timer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a very good example of an [SystemTrayNotifyIcon with Event Generator](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/systemtraynotifyicon.aspx) over at the CodeProject .

I've looked at this project before but didn't end up using it, due to my artistic inabilities, but the example given does the job quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/IconAnimation.aspx and http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nkumar/AnimateSysteminCSharp11292005235157PM/AnimateSysteminCSharp.aspx for a more recent example.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/IconAnimation.aspx link points toward a VC/Win32 example which the OP might not be interested in.