# Blink tray icon in tray application (C# windows form)

Tags: c#, winforms, system-tray

I created one tray application. It's icon will be change based on condition.
At one point I want functionality in which my icon should be blink like it can be gif.

Comment: What have you tried? As is now, your question is off-topic as asking for off-site resource or tutorial.

Comment: [I bet someone got a really nice bonus for that feature](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061101-03/?p=29153). Tray icons aren't meant to be used for things like this (and behaviour like this is why windows now defaults to hiding most icons)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animate tray icon while processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536890/animate-tray-icon-while-processing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tray Icon animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559853/tray-icon-animation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Window application flash like orange on taskbar when minimize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309827/window-application-flash-like-orange-on-taskbar-when-minimize)