# Drawing a JComponent inside a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, jcomponent, null-layout-manager

I am trying to display a JComponent inside a JPanel.
I am using null layout because location of the components can be changed during runtime and I have to control them.

But the following code does not work. The JComponent only becomes visible on display if I explicity call the "paintComponent" method, which I think is not good practice.

My JComponent Class

```
public class MyIcon extends JComponent 
{
    private double xPos;
    private double yPos;
    private double radius = 30;

    public MyIcon(double xPos, double yPos)
    {
            this.xPos = xPos;
            this.yPos = yPos;
            this.setBounds((int)xPos, (int)yPos, (int)radius, (int)radius);
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)radius, (int)radius ) );
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
            return ( new Dimension( (int)radius, (int)radius ) );
    }

    public Dimension getMinimumSize() 
    {
            return new Dimension((int)radius, (int)radius);
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.drawOval( (int)xPos, (int)yPos, (int)radius, (int)radius);

            g2d.fillOval((int)xPos, (int)yPos, (int)radius, (int)radius);

            System.out.println("Icon.paintComponnet() called");
    }
}
```

My Panel Class

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel
{
    private MyIcon myIcon;
    private Graphics2D graphics;
    private int width = 700;
    private int height = 500;

    public MyPanel()
    {
        myIcon = new MyIcon(20,30);
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        setLayout(null);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setPreferredSize( new Dimension(width, height) );
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        add( myIcon );
        myIcon.repaint();       
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        graphics = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g);
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        System.out.println("MyPanel.paintComponnet() called");

        // why my Icon only gets painted if I explicitly call for it ?

        //myIcon.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

My Frame Class

```
public class Editor {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Editor editor = new Editor();
    }

    private MyPanel myPanel;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JToolBar toolBar;

    public Editor()
    {
        myPanel = new MyPanel();
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Editor");
        Container content = frame.getContentPane();
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(15,15));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        content.add(myPanel,BorderLayout.WEST);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
     }
}
```

Comment: `public class Icon extends JComponent`, don't use `reserved Java words, JComponents namens or API names` as custom class_name, use `MyIcon` for example

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: See also this very simple icon editing view: [`Grid`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2901472/230513).

Answer (score 1):

- I'd be use [paintIcon() for Class that returns Icon Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Icon.html)
- [public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Icon.html#paintIcon%28java.awt.Component,%20java.awt.Graphics,%20int,%20int%29)
- [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12707482/714968)

Comment: +1 for implementing the `Icon` interface, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a good approach would be that the Icon class would not extend `JComponent` but would be just a simple object.

Then, you rename the current `Icon.paintComponent` you have to something like `drawIcon` and call the `drawIcon` method from the `MyPanel.paintComponent` directly and passing the reference to the Graphics object.

This way you don't have to wonder about using a null layout and you can control the place to display the icon to by just using the `Graphics(2d)` APIs.

Comment: That would solve this problem but would not answer me why my code doesnt work properly.