# How can I listen to clicks on a message of TrayIcon

Tags: java, swing, awt, system-tray, trayicon

I want to automatically do an action when the user clicks the balloon message which I pop from a **TrayIcon** with **trayIcon.displayMessage()**.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you can to add [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) to the [Message in SystemTray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html)
- [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12707482/714968) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12707482/714968)

Comment: 70k! congratulations ;)

Comment: @Maroun Maroun cca <70k thanks

Comment: @Bill the Lizard (bump looks like as everything here is possible) this is about of un_documented methods, btw this one I few times asked to add to offical API