# Calling trayIcon.displayMessage() from method

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, system-tray, trayicon

I know below way to show a balloon message:

```java
something.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        trayIcon.displayMessage("Tray", "Icon", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
    }
});
```

But is there any way to call trayIcon.displayMessage() from a method?

```
void showMsg(){
trayIcon.displayMessage("Tray", "Icon", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
}
```

doesn't work and I have no idea what to do next.

This is how I created trayIcon:

```
if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
        SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
        windowItem = new MenuItem("Show");
        MenuItem openSettings = new MenuItem("Settings");
        MenuItem areaShot = new MenuItem("sth");
        MenuItem fullShot = new MenuItem("sth");
        MenuItem aboutItem = new MenuItem("About");
        MenuItem exitItem = new MenuItem("Exit");
        popup.add(windowItem);
        popup.add(openSettings);
        popup.addSeparator();
        popup.add(areaShot);
        popup.add(fullShot);
        popup.add(aboutItem);
        popup.add(exitItem);
        trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "App", popup);
        trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
}
```

Comment: Is this all the code you can provide?

Comment: Added code with creating trayIcon. Anything else needed?

Comment: Does the code compile?

Comment: Of course it does, the whole program works great, but now I need to show a message and the least invasive way to do this is a balloon message.

Comment: You might check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12707482/230513) or [nearby](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A714968+SystemTray).

Comment: Making TrayIcon static helped and now displayMessage() works everywhere.